# urllib module error! AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was currently playing with the 'urllib' module in python, and tried this to extract source code of a website:

```
import urllib
temp = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.quora.com/#')
```

However, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       temp = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.quora.com/#') AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

I am using Python 2.7.5 by the way.

Comment: Where is the documentation telling you about "urllib.request.urlopen"?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/urllib2.html

Comment: Python 3 documentation = Python 2 documentation? Think about it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like you are reading [Python 3.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen).

It's [`urllib.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) in Python 2.x.

Comment: Yup, works now! Was indeed reading the wrong documentation afterall.